# nodejs express-busboy req.body is empty

Tags: node.js, express

I want to access to req.body.
When the request body contains a JSON structure with few elements, it works fine.
But when the JSON structure contains a huge amount of data (image for example), req.body is empty.
Maybe it is because the data are not fully uploaded but how can i wait ?

Comment: Can you provide some more context? Where are you trying to get JSON from? Whats your request look like? I don't have enough information to start demoing a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val) {    
          req.body[fieldname] = val;
    });
```

give a try to this before finish event. And you will get your data completely on finish in

```
busboy.on('finish' ......)
```

Comment: I am using express; so i have something like that: app.post('/myroute',function(req,res) { ... } and i should i do this for web forms too ?

Comment: i have an error Error: Unsupported content type: application/json